# Chrome bug? Mouse movement event triggering on click in chrome 40.0.22x

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

[I reproduced the effect in this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azwwRb)

Move the mouse over the grey area, and keep it there, even let go. You will see the mouse counter increasing every second.

HTML

```
<div> Please move your mouse over the red area and then remove your hand from the mouse, see the mouse movement counter increase every second. <br/><span></span></<div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  font-size: 20px;
}

b{
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

JS

```
mousemovements = 0;

$(function(){
  $("div").on("mousemove", function(){
    mousemovements += 1;
  $("span").html("<b>mouse moved: " + mousemovements+"   </b>");
})});
```

This bug is not visible in firefox 35

Comment: What red area? An no, I don’t see the counter increasing after I stop moving the mouse … maybe yours has a bit of the shivers?

Comment: I can't reproduce it, either.

Comment: tried in latest chrome (40.0.2214.91 m)  and FF, could not reproduce

Comment: @CBroe If it were a problem with the mouse, why wouldn't it affect him in FF?

Comment: @Barmar: Dunno, but could be that there’s a different kind of threshold implemented from when a coordinate change actually constitutes “movement” or something like that …

Comment: It appears to be a known issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=327114

Comment: I can reproduce it in his pen by right-clicking in the grey area. The context menu pops up and down, and every time it increments the counter.

Comment: I unplugged my mouse and disabled my trackpad. Problem still occurs.

Comment: I get the problem without using mousedown nor up. I am using windows 8.1 
it seems to be limited to windows versions

Comment: clicking appears to trigger the mousemove event, which is unexpected, but not what I gathered from the title of your question